# Does Terraform perform interpolation in provider declarations?

Tags: terraform

I am trying to declare the following Terraform provider:

```
provider "mysql" {                                                              
    endpoint = "${aws_db_instance.main.endpoint}:3306"                   
    username = "root"                                                           
    password = "root"                                                           
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* dial tcp: lookup ${aws_db_instance.main.endpoint}: invalid domain name
```

It seems that Terraform is not performing interpolation on my endpoint string, yet I don't see anything in the documentation about this -- what gives?

Comment: What does your resource definition for `aws_db_instance` `main` look like?

Comment: Also, the example in the mysql provider doc seems to imply that the `aws_db_instance...endpoint` returns the port as part of the output, so you shouldn't need to append it again.  https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/mysql/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. There's an example in the docs at https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/mysql/

```
# Configure the MySQL provider based on the outcome of
# creating the aws_db_instance.
provider "mysql" {
    endpoint = "${aws_db_instance.default.endpoint}"
    username = "${aws_db_instance.default.username}"
    password = "${aws_db_instance.default.password}"
}
```

Comment: The vscode terraform plugin might underline HCL2 interpolation statements as though they are illegal though.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar set of error messages ("connect failed," "invalid domain lookup") and looked into this a bit.  I hope this helps you or someone else working across cloud and database providers in Terraform.

This seems to come down to the MySQL provider attempting to establish a database connection as soon as it's initialized, which could be a problem if you're trying to build a database server *and configure the database / grants on it* as part of the same Terraform run.  Providers get initialized based on Terraform finding a resource owned by that provider in your Terraform code, and since this connection attempt happens when the provider gets initialized, you can't work around this with `-target=<SPECIFIC RESOURCE>`.

The workarounds I can think of would be to have a codebase for setting up the database server and a different codebase for setting up the database grants and suchlike ... or to have Terraform kick off a script that does that work for you (with dynamic parameters, of course!).  Either way, you're effectively removing `mysql_*` resources from your initial Terraform run and that's what fixes this.

There are a couple of code changes that probably need to happen here - the Terraform MySQL provider would need to delay connecting to the database until Terraform tells it to run an operation on a resource, and it *may* be necessary to look at how Terraform handles dependencies across providers.  I tried hacking in deferred connection logic just for the `mysql_database` resource to see if that solved all my problems and Terraform still complained about a dependency loop in the graph.

You can track the MySQL provider issue here:

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-mysql/issues/2

And the comments from before providers were split into their own releasable codebases:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/5687